# DHCP server assigning same IP address even if Computer is connected in different VLAN

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp, dhcp-server, dhcp-option

DHCP Server OS - Windows Server Standard 2008 R2

DHCP Client OS - Windows 7, Linux based OS etc..

I have configured DHCP Server on Windows Server Standard 2008 R2 with SuperScope. Let assume that i have two Scope in SuperScope.
VLAN 8 and VLAN 7.
and with help of IP helper command i have configured Switch and assigned Port 10 with VLAN 8 and Port 11 with VLAN 7

I am not facing any problem if i connect my Laptop first time to any of the port i.e Port 10 and Port 11, i am getting proper IP address for particular VLAN i.e VLAN 8 and VLAN 7 ip address respectively.

but if i am connecting same Laptop on Port 11 and after few minutes if i connect the same laptop on Port 10 than i am getting same VLAN 7 ip address on both port.

I have tried to find out with Wireshark about root problem, I get to know that I am facing problem due to Client requesting the same ip address from DHCP server with Option 50 and also due to lease period i.e DHCP server holding ip address of that client till lease period is over.

To resolve this problem i have to run ipconfig /release without disconnecting my Laptop and than after disconnecting my laptop i have to run - " net stop dhcp " and "net start dhcp", and than connect to different port on Switch, To Resolve this problem.

Is there any solution or workaround without running this command, or without restarting my laptop. Also i don't want to delete the ip address from dhcp server manually. Is there any automated process for the same. Please help.

I am just wondering, how dhcp server is configured in other organization. Don't you face such type of problem, if yes, what do you do?

Comment: Dhcp helper scope added correctly on your dhcp server?

Comment: You're using Superscopes wrong. From Microsoft: **A superscope allows a DHCP server to provide leases from more than one scope to clients on a single physical network** - You have two VLAN's, therefore you have two physical networks, therefore you need a standard scope for each VLAN.